# Android : resValue variables could not be resolved in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am following an android example from vogella.com about Retrofit.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

I get stuck where one is supposed to do the following:

add the stackapp id and key

According to Vogella

*After you registered your application, you get a Client Id and a Key . As   we want to keep them out of a possible version control system, we import them  into our project using gradle. To do so, go to your gradle home directory  (.gradle/ in your users home directory) and paste the following lines into your  gradle.properties file (create one, if you can’t find it). Of course, replace  yourKey and yourClientId with your corresponding values from Stackapps.*

I went to this directory and created a new file

```
gradle.properties
```

and in that file I added the keys

```
key=xxxxxxxx
client_id=xxxx
```

and then in the gradle.properties i added the following in deafultconfig {

```
 resValue("string", "key", project.key)
 resValue("string", "client_id", project.client_id)
```

But both the key and the client_id's could not be resolved.

What could the solution be to this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "But both the key and the client_id's could not be resolved"?

Comment: @azizbekian - I mean android studio tells me "cannot resolve symbol key" ... "cannot resolve symbol "client_id"

Comment: Clean project and build again. The setup you mention should work without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the sintax :

```
resValue "string", "key", project.key
resValue "string", "client_id", project.client_id
```

And dont forget to add the variables inside your gradle file:

```
ext.key = "your_key"
ext.client_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter should be a String, and you may should define the key and cliend_id in local.properties and use code below:

```
Properties lp = new Properties()
lp.load(newInputStreamReader(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

resValue "string", "key", p.getProperty('key', '0')//default "0"
resValue "string", "client_id", p.getProperty('client_id', '0')
```